# Передать содержимое класса с другого сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery

На стороннем сайте существует класс:

```
<span class="small-star-bar">
```

Данный класс требуется передать на мой сайт в данный ID:

```
<div id="m">  </div>
```

код для загрузки данного класса:

```
let x = site.ru;
$( "#m" ).load(x  " #small-star-bar " );
```

Не получается передача из класса,  в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Для ЯваСкрипт-запросов к другим сайтом нужно у своего браузера отключить 
Content Security Policy

Эта политика может запрещать ЯваСкрипту получать контент другого домена.